# React BDD with custom api call (Mock response)

Tags: reactjs, selenium-webdriver, bdd, cucumberjs

I doing BDD with cucumberjs, selenium-webdriver & react.
In one of scenario, I want to make Mock API call instead of actually API call.

Example -> I am calling

```
http://example.com/v1/getData
```

But I want to call

```
http://myapi.com/v1/getData
```

without modifying actual code

Comment: Depends on API in use. Is it Fetch? Then mock Fetch.

Comment: I don't want to modify code and API, I just want to override API response.

Comment: So If I'm following you correctly you want to  
1. Catch the request the front end to sending  
2. Manipulate the request  
3. Send the manipulated request

Comment: 'API' stands for 'JavaScript API'. There are at least two basic APIs, XHR and Fetch. Again, it depends on how the request is done. For instance, Axios is widely used because it can be easily mocked. Since the question doesn't explain that, it cannot be answered.

Comment: @RaymondKelly yes

Comment: @RahulG see my answer below on resources to use

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriverajax

Try googling `selenium intercept http request js` and you will get some good resourcs

Comment: @RahulG Cucumber-js should have nothing to do with it. Cucumber-js simply drives the tests. What is not working?

Comment: i am not using web driver io

Comment: @RahulG your responses are really bad. You are not going to get an answer if you don't provide information

Answer (score 0):

What about using an ENV var for the domain and setting that ENV var to http://example.com or http://myapi.com when appropriate?

Also, if you are looking for an easy way to setup those mock endpoints checkout Mock/it: https://mockit.io. You can claim a dedicated subdomain just like you are hoping to do. Disclaimer: this is a side project I recently released and would love any feedback on it!